# Redirect Subdomain to domain while preserving the path and query string

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a subdomain and I want to redirect to the main domain (using `.htaccess`) like so:

1. `https://abc.example.com` I want to redirect it to `https://www.example.com`
2. `https://abc.example.com/path/page-name` to `https://www.example.com/path/page-name`
3. `https://abc.example.com/path/page-name?test=12&test1=12` to `https://www.example.com/path/page-name?test=12&test1=12`

Please suggest how I can do it.

I have already tried the below solution but its not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/suberror  [L,R]
```

I am using Laravel.

Comment: You say you have "a subdomain" (singular), but you have a _wildcard_ (any subdomain) pattern in your regex? Where does the subdomain point to on the filesystem in relation to the main domain? The same place?

Answer (score 1):

At this line :

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/suberror  [L,R]
```

There is no `pattern` means , regex checked against requested URI .

Change it to this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1  [L,R]
```

This part `^(.*)$` is `pattern` and it will be presented in `substitution` by this `$1`

If it is Ok , Change `[L,R]` to `[L,R=301]` to be permanent redirection because `R` alone means `R=302` which is temporary .

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- You have 1 subdomain (as stated in your example)
- The subdomain and main domain point to the same area on the filesystem (they share a common root).

The try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}  [R,L]
```

The URL-path from the request is held in the `REQUEST_URI` server variable. The query string from the request is passed through to the *substitution* (target) without any additional work.